# @RequestParam is null when accessed in @ModelAttribute method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am using am working on a project where users can choose to either start with a new form submission, or continue with a form submission that they had started previously.  I'm using a the @ModelAttribute notation to generate new object for new form submissions.  This much works great.  Now I'm trying to get the information form the database to pre-fill inforomation in the object based on a given id and I've run into a snag. I'm trying to use @RequestParam to get the id that is passed in using a form submission but the id is comming back null. I can see that the id is being sent as part of the request string but it isn't making it to the @ModelAttribute method.  Here is what I have so far.

Form that is submitted to send regId so that form can be pre-populated

```
<form id="preregistration" action="/Homepage/Pre-Registration" method="post">
<input type="text" name="view" id="view" value="preprocess"/>
<select name="regId" id="regId">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1234">1234</option>
    <option value="4567">4567</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Model Attribute method

```
@ModelAttribute("event")
public Event createDefaultEvent(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer regId){
    log.debug("regId: {}", regId);
    if (regId == null){
        log.debug("make new event object");
        return new Event();
    } else {
        log.debug("retrieve event with id: {}", regId);
        return eventDao.get(regId);
    }
}
```

Request Mapping Method

```
@RequestMapping(params = "view=preprocess")
public String getPreProcessInformation(@ModelAttribute("event") Event event)
    throws Exception{
        return "redirect:/preregistration.do?"+Page.EVENT.getView();
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why my regId is null in the @ModelAttruibute method when I submit my form?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell it what the name of the param you want to read in is:

```
@RequestParam(value="regId", required = false)
```

That names of method parameters are not something that's available via reflection at runtime.  Spring can't figure out that you named your parameter 'regId' in java code, you need to tell it so.

Edit:

Also some more academic rambling, ModelAttribute methods are best used for providing reference data that is fixed in the scope of the View you're building.  Transactional items that you're planning to bind form fields onto should usually be generated by the actual request handler methods.  This becomes extra-special important if you use an OpenSession/EntityManagerInView filter and/or the @SessionAttributes annotation.